# infinite loop in pre_get_posts when filtering pages in wordpress admin

Tags: php, wordpress, filter

I have been able to add drop down lists in the filters available for pages in WordPress admin.

The list only displays the root pages.

When I select a root page and click on filter, I want to display all the pages which are under this root page.

I have this code in my functions.php, but it runs into an infinite loop and I have not been able to fix it. Any help appreciated.

```
// add filter to lists in admin
add_action(
    'pre_get_posts',
    'kpcms_filter_pages_request');

function kpcms_filter_pages_request(
    $query)
{
    // add filter to list of Training Pages in admin
    if ((strpos(
        $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],
        '/wp-admin/edit.php') !== false) && isset(
        $_GET['admin_filter_KPCMS_training'])) {
        if (! empty(
            $_GET['admin_filter_KPCMS_training'])) {
            error_log(
                'add filters by training');
            add_filter(
                'posts_where',
                'kpcms_filter_pages_by_training',
                10,
                1);
        }
    }
}

function kpcms_filter_pages_by_training(
    $where = '')
{
    $where .= 'AND wp_' . get_current_blog_id() . '_posts.ID IN(' . $_GET['admin_filter_KPCMS_training'];
    $childPages = json_decode(
        "[" . substr(
            kpcms_get_child_posts_JSON(
                "page",
                $_GET['admin_filter_KPCMS_training'],
                [],
                true,
                array(
                    "publish",
                    "future",
                    "draft"
                )),
            1) . "]",
        true);
    foreach ($childPages as $childPage) {
        $where .= "," . $childPage['id'];
    }
    $where .= ")";
    // Remove the filter to call this function, as we don't want it any more
    remove_filter(
        'posts_where',
        'kpcms_filter_pages_by_training',
        10,
        1);
    return $where;
}

// get hierarchical array of IDs and titles of all subpages of current page
function kpcms_get_child_posts_JSON(
    $postType,
    $postId,
    $array_saved_pages,
    $first_call,
    $postStatus = array(
        "publish"
    ))
{
    $searchTags = [
        "\\",
        '"',
        "\r\n"
    ];
    $replaceTags = [
        "\\\\",
        '\\"',
        ""
    ];
    static $child_Pages;
    // if first call empty $child_Pages
    if ($first_call) {
        $child_Pages = '';
    }
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => $postType,
        'post_status' => $postStatus,
        'sort_order' => 'asc',
        'sort_column' => 'menu_order',
        'parent' => $postId
    );
    $children = get_pages(
        $args);
    if ($children !== false) {
        foreach ($children as $child) {
            if (in_array(
                $child->ID,
                $array_saved_pages)) {
                $selectedState = ', "state" : { "selected" : "TRUE" }';
            } else {
                $selectedState = "";
            }
            $child_Pages .= ',{"id" : ' . $child->ID . ', "parent" : "' . $postId . '", "text" : "' . str_replace(
                $searchTags,
                $replaceTags,
                $child->post_title) . '"' . $selectedState . '}';
            kpcms_get_child_posts_JSON(
                $postType,
                $child->ID,
                $array_saved_pages,
                false,
                $postStatus); // 3rd argument set to false to fill $child_Pages
        }
    }
    return $child_Pages;
}
```